# Passing Array Parameter to SQL command javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, arrays, sql-in

I'm trying to pass a dynamic array to a executeSql. I'm passing the SQL to the IN as array.

```js
let lor_text_Array = [];
if (lor_text == "TEST 1, 2, 3") {
    lor_text_Array = ["TEST 1", "TEST 2", "TEST 3"];
}
else {
    lor_text_Array.push("TEST 4")
    lor_text_Array.push("TEST 5")
}

let sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM SUBMISSION WHERE REV IN (' + lor_text_Array + ')ORDER BY ID DESC'; 
app.db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(sql_query, [], loadItemsSYNCED, app.onError);});
```

however an error occured while executing sql Error object Object

Comment: You should format your array as a `string` value manually. Because it's formatted by JS as `object Object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your string values do not contain embedded single quotes, you use `map` and `join` to generate the `IN` list, as follows:

```
let lor_in_list = lor_text_Array.map(function (a) { return "'" + a + "'"; }).join(",");
let sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM SUBMISSION WHERE REV IN (' + lor_in_list + ')ORDER BY ID DESC';
```

To handle possible embedded single quotes:

```
let lor_in_list = lor_text_Array.map(function (a) { 
    return "'" + a.replace("'", "''") + "'"; 
}).join(",");
```

Comment: ok you mean when i create the array like 

let  lor_text_Array = ["TEST 1", "TEST 2", "TEST 3"]; it is not a comma seperated string?

Comment: can i avoid single quotes when creating the array?